# delete record and move previous not working

Tags: ms-access, vba

I'm trying to delete a record and then move to the one before the deleted record.  But I can't get it to work, and now I'm getting

> run-time error 2046 The command or action 'DeleteReord' isn't available now.

What am I doing wrong here?  How should I handle this?

```
    Private Sub Command24_Click()
On Error GoTo Err_Command24_Click

If Me![dbo_HR_Trainings Subform].Form.Recordset.RecordCount > 0 Then
        MsgBox "You cannot delete a category that has members.", vbOKOnly
        GoTo Exit_Command24_Click
Else

        Select Case MsgBox("Are you sure you want to delete this category?", vbYesNo, "Are you sure?")
                Case vbYes
                        DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdSelectRecord
                        DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdDeleteRecord

                        DoCmd.GoToRecord , , acPrevious
                Case Else
        End Select
End If

Exit_Command24_Click:
    Exit Sub

Err_Command24_Click:
    MsgBox Err.Description
    Resume Exit_Command24_Click

End Sub
```

Comment: Are you able to delete the record by using your mouse: Select the record in the Form -> press Del? What message are you getting?

Comment: @IgorTurman -Its in form mode, not datasheet mode.  And I have a button that I placed on the form which calls this code.

Comment: That's fine. Seems like you hide the record selection button. Could you please make that button visible and try to manually delete the record?

Comment: @IgorTurman -I turned Record Selectors and Navigation Buttons on, but I"m not getting a delete option.

Comment: maybe your form does not allow deletion... check form properties (Allow Delete)

Comment: @IgorTurman -Don't know how this got changed, but that was part of the problem.  Now it deletes, but how to go to previous record after delete?

Comment: Since you have Navigation buttons, can you navigate to the previous record after you manually delete the record? How many times do you need to click Prev button?

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you get the error in Debug mode. Do not set a breakpoint on DoCmd commands. This will **always** fail.

If this is not the case, then here you can find one of the possible ways to accomplish what you want by using Bookmark:
http://www.granite.ab.ca/access/positioning_on_a_continuous_form.htm

Please note the example is for continuous forms but you can get the idea.

Comment: I'm not really seeing how I can use this here?

Comment: In short, before Delete you need to "bookmark" the previous record. After Delete, just move to the Bookmark.