# Record is deleted error after executing vb code (that deletes the record)

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a problem with one of my databases that I have had for some time that is somewhat of an annoyance.

I have a form in continuous view in which the user must fill out some information for each record and then click a "commit" button (for each record).

Based on the values entered for that record, the "commit" button will first insert the information in one of two tables, then delete the record from the temporary table from which the form is querying.

psuedocode for it is here:

```
IF x.checked && y > 70 then
  db.execute "Insert into tblCompleted values (me.empID,'completed',me.y);
else
  db.execute "insert into tblIncompleted values (me.empid, 'incomplete', 'me.y);
end if
db.execute "delete * from tblTemporary WHERE empid = me.empID"
 'form.requery
'form.refresh
```

I will sometimes get a 'record is deleted' runtime error, sometimes twice for the same record. However, all operations do work. After it has been completed, however, the record shows ##DELETED. To fix this, I put a Form.refresh and Form.requery statement at the end of my code. This will eliminate the ##DELETED record, but often throw me a "record is deleted" error.

Before you say "why are you using two tables, couldn't this just be modeled with one table", this is a simplified version of what I'm actually doing, and to me, using two tables makes more sense design-wise.

My main concern is this run time error. I could just catch it and leave it unhandled, but I'd prefer actually fixing it and sorting out this buggy form. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the reason is that immediately after deleting the record, your form is still trying to show it. The answer in a related [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10538098/delete-record-and-move-previous-not-working?rq=1) suggests moving the bookmark to the previous record before deleting the current one using code like [this](http://www.granite.ab.ca/access/positioning_on_a_continuous_form.htm).

Comment: I like this. This also solves the 'jumping to the top of the screen' problem that some of my users have complained about after completing a record. I'll need to save this code snippet to my arsenal

Answer (score 1):

Remove the RecordSource before deleting the table and then re-add it.

```
form.RecordSouce = ""
db.execute "delete * from tblTemporary WHERE empid = me.empID"
form.RecordSouce = "tblTemporary"
```

Answer (score 1):

I know it's been a couple of years since this was posted but I had the same issue (Access 2010) and, after reading the comments above, came up with the solution below of moving to the next record before deleting.

```
        delBatchID = [ID]

        Me.Recordset.MoveNext

        'delete the batch headers
        qString = "Delete From T_Imported_Files Where ID = " & delBatchID & ";"
        CurrentDb.Execute qString

        'update the form to show that the batch is gone.
        Form.Requery
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
Dim lEmpID as Long
lEmpID = Me!EmpID
DoCmd.SetWarnings False
DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdDeleteRecord
DoCmd.SetWarnings True
db.Execute "DELETE * FROM tblTemporary WHERE empid = " & lEmpID
```

The basic idea here is that you can probably delete one record from one table using the normal Delete command. This will likely be enough to convince your form that the record doesn't exist anymore.

Depending on how you have referential integrity configured (with Delete Cascade?), you might not even have to do that last db.Execute.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old thread, but I just ran into this and solved it by moving the focus to a control outside of the subform.  The issue seemed to be that I was still on the record I was deleting.

```
    Dim response As VbMsgBoxResult 
    Dim strSQL As String

    response = MsgBox("Are you sure you want to delete this record?", vbYesNo + vbQuestion, "Delete Record?")

    Select Case response
        Case vbYes
            strSQL = "DELETE FROM TABLENAME WHERE ID = " & Me.ID
            Forms("ParentForm").Form.Controls("TextBox1").SetFocus
            If ExecuteSQL(strSQL) = False Then MsgBox "There was an error deleting this record." & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "If the problem persists, please contact your             System Administrator.", vbOKOnly + vbExclamation, "Error"
            Me.Requery
        Case vbNo

    End Select

Public Function ExecuteSQL(sSQL As String) As Boolean
On Error GoTo HandleError

    DoCmd.SetWarnings False
'    Debug.Print sSQL
    DoCmd.RunSQL sSQL

    ExecuteSQL = True

Exit_ExecuteSQL:
'    Debug.Print sSQL
    DoCmd.SetWarnings True
    Exit Function

HandleError:
    GeneralErrorHandler err.Number, err.Description, "modDatabaseCalls", "ExecuteSQL", True
    ExecuteSQL = False
    Resume Exit_ExecuteSQL

End Function
```