# Listbox will be block after delete and then insert data

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I hav e a listbox, which shows me only a value (it is related to a table with only two coloumns. I fill this table from a text file). I would like, If a new text file is loaded, then the old data should be deleted and the new data should be shown to me.

I can do this task with my code, but listbox will be block and I am not able to scroll through data (without delete, it works fine, but the new data is added after the old data)

would you please tell me how can I solve this problem? and why this problem is occured?

here is my code:

```
Private Sub Command11_Click()
Dim ifile As Integer

Dim name As String
Let ifile = FreeFile
 name = util1.fDateiName("*.lab", "Lable")
DoCmd.RunSQL ("DELETE * FROM tb_lable_Daten") 'if I delete this Delete command , it works fine( the list box will not be dlocked
Open name For Input As ifile
While Not EOF(ifile)
Line Input #ifile, entireline
 DoCmd.RunSQL ("INSERT INTO tb_lable_Daten (name) VALUES ('" & entireline & "');")
Wend
List5.Requery
List5.SetFocus
MsgBox ("Successfully saved")
End Sub
```

Comment: Could you clarify the problem? What do you mean "listbox will be block"? What part isn't working?

Comment: As I said, I am not able to select the values in the list. If i close the form and then open the form It works fine (I can select the values)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it :)

I have read this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13053845/record-is-deleted-error-after-executing-vb-code-that-deletes-the-record). If I change my code to:

```
...
 Me.RecordSource = ""
 DoCmd.RunSQL ("DELETE * FROM tb_lable_Daten")
 Me.RecordSource = "SELECT name FROM tb_lable_Daten"
...
```

that works fine